# How to reset the upload key for a react native expo app that will be used to sign APKs to upload to Google Play?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, google-play-console

I reach out to google and they sent me this:

Here’s how to generate and register a new upload key:

1. Follow the instructions in the Android Studio Help Center to generate a new key. It must be different from any previous keys. Alternatively, you can use the following command line to generate a new key:

`keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks`

This key must be a 2048 bit RSA key and have 25-year validity.

2. Export the certificate for that key to PEM format:

`keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore.jks`

3. Send us the `upload_certificate.pem` file.

My question is how to do this with a react native expo app?

Comment: There's no difference for upload key generation even if you're using react-native. Open any project or this project in android studio and follow the Keystore generation process. Alternatively, you can also generate the key using the command line instructions that you mentioned in the question. React native also has docs for the same -> https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.

Comment: I´ve the same problem here. Did you solve this Manny ?

Comment: I went through this process on my mac, but now I do not know what to do now that google has reset.  I have a .jks and a .pem file, but eas does not know about them.  How do I move forward?    Google's email back to me said:

Make sure to update your keystores in the following locations:

Local machine
Locked on-site server (varying ACLs)
Cloud machine (varying ACLs) 
Dedicated secrets management services
(git) repos

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the new keystore using Expo EAS cli

`eas credentials -p android`

The keystore will automatically be put in place in Expo EAS and you will get the jks file which you should backup somewhere safe.

You can then get the pem file using

`keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore @organisation__app-name.jks`

Remember to replace "upload" with your key alias and "@organisation__app-name.jks" with your jks filename.